# Helm update - rerun the Job again

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to rerun JOB again on helm upgrade.
My Job template Looks like

Job -

```
annotations:
    "helm.sh/hook": pre-install,pre-upgrade,pre-rollback
    "helm.sh/hook-delete-policy": before-hook-creation
    "helm.sh/hook-weight": "3"
```

and configmaps

```
annotations:
"helm.sh/hook": pre-install, pre-upgrade
"helm.sh/hook-weight": "-10"
"helm.sh/hook-delete-policy": hook-succeeded
```

Work fine when - "helm install " but fails to rerun during "helm upgrage"
Whereas configmaps are getting reloaded during - "helm upgrade"

I am using helm 2.x

Comment: Surely it is not the case for the hook not working, but can you try removing the space between pre-install, and pre-upgrade? Just to be sure

Comment: It looks like you have similar issue as described here: [Github.com: Helm should delete job after it is successfully finished #1769](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/1769). Also could you tell which exact version of `Helm` are you running?

Comment: I am using - v2.12.3